# Standard SQL String to Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string date formatted as 20190101 that I'm trying to convert to 2019-01-01. How would I do this in standard? I know in legacy I could simply do date('20190101'), but not sure how to do this in standard.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use [`PARSE_DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date):

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20190101')
```

Comment: @ThomasNguyen . . . The case makes a difference for the pattern.  Lower case is a two-digit year.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',  '20190101')
```

Format elements for date is here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date